# sum of maximum element in all subarays of size >1 starting from every element in an array

Tags: arrays

We are given an array and we are asked to find the sum of the maximum element of every sub arrays of size >1 starting from every element of an array. for example if the array is [1,2,3,4] then the result should be [9, 7, 4, 0]. We are asked only to find the maximum element of every sub array of size > 1. so for 1 it is max(1,2) + max(1, 2, 3) + max(1, 2, 3, 4) which is 9. The given array need not be sorted. How to solve this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a result array. Sort the input array, then iterate through it backwards 2 elements at a time, appending the sum of the two elements at each iteration to the result array. This is the fastest way to solve this problem. I won't write you the exact answer, but this should be enough to help you.

Comment: for eg if the given input array is 2,1,6,4 the answer is [2+6+6, 6 + 6, 6, 0] which is [14, 12, 6, 0]. But if we sort this array it will become 1 , 2, 4, 6 which from your method will give the result  [max(1,2) + 10 ,max(2,4) + 6 ,6 ,0].  which is [12, 10, 6, 0];